# Зачем минус примитивным типам данных?

Tags: java, byte

Есть массив байтов. Необходимо извлечь 12 младших бит первых двух байтов - порядковый номер (4096 значений). Правильно ли решаю задачу?
Для наглядности такое решение:

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append(String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(b1 & 0xFF)).replaceAll(" ", "0"));
        stringBuilder.append(String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(b2 & 0xFF)).replaceAll(" ", "0"));
        return Integer.parseInt(stringBuilder.substring(4), 2);
```

С побитовыми операциями (возвращается int):

```
return ((byte1 & 0xFF) << 8 | (byte2 & 0xFF)) & 0xFFF;
```

Почему в 10-й системе исчисления байт представлен диапазоном -128..+128, а не 0..256? Зачем при расширении типа у "отрицательного" байта старшие биты автоматом заполняются единицами. И не теряю ли я данные, используя маску для исключения этих самых единиц.

Comment: `Правильно ли решаю задачу?` какую задачу?

Comment: если у вас несколько несвязанных вопросов - задавайте их отдельными вопросами.

Comment: Подкорректировал

Comment: На байты не имеет смысла накладывать маску 0xFF. Диапазон знаковых -128..+127, беззнаковых 0..255

Comment: У вас всё ещё два вопроса в одном посте

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Java нет беззнаковых типов (за исключением char). Почему - историки Java, вероятно, знают. Дядюшка Гослинг говорит о простоте и необходимом минимуме. Без беззнаковых обойтись, в общем, можно, а вот без отрицательных неприятно.

> Gosling: For me as a language designer, which I don't really count
> myself as these days, what "simple" really ended up meaning was could
> I expect J. Random Developer to hold the spec in his head. That
> definition says that, for instance, Java isn't -- and in fact a lot of
> these languages end up with a lot of corner cases, things that nobody
> really understands. Quiz any C developer about unsigned, and pretty
> soon you discover that almost no C developers actually understand what
> goes on with unsigned, what unsigned arithmetic is. Things like that
> made C complex. The language part of Java is, I think, pretty simple.
> The libraries you have to look up.

`Почему в 10-й системе исчисления байт представлен диапазоном -128..+128, а не 0..256?`

Байт в памяти представлен восемью битами, а уж как их интерпретировать - зависит от языка, типа данных, программиста. 256 возможных значений - это `-128..+127` для int8 (в Java только так), или `0..255` для uint8, или один AnsiChar (в Java отсутствуют).

`Зачем при расширении типа у "отрицательного" байта старшие биты автоматом заполняются единицами` - дык чтобы сохранялось значение

```
-1 = 0b11111111 = 0b1111111111111111
```

если заполнить нулями, то получится

```
0b0000000011111111 = 255
```

`И не теряю ли я данные` -  для извлечения битов - нет. Обратите внимание, что формула попроще:

```
byte byte1 = -1; //0b11111111
byte byte2 = 1;
int r = (byte1 & 0x0F) << 8 | byte2;
System.out.println(r);
```

Даёт `3841 = 0b111100000001`.

Comment: Благодарю за развернутый ответ